# Firebase functions 2nd generation on Emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to run 2nd generation firebase function onCall with Emulator.

based on [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions) this is the solution:

```js
import { getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions";

const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
```

but in my case, it's not working. here is my code:

```js
onst firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: '',
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const functions = getFunctions(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
  connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099', { disableWarnings: true });

}

export const helloWorld = httpsCallableFromURL<unknown, THelloResponse>(
  functions,
  'https://hello-cp54mvsyeq-uc.a.run.app'
);
```

with `httpsCallable` it's ok.

```
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.0",
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What OS are you using? There's a bug on some ipv6 machines where "localhost" doesn't resolve correctly. Try using `127.0.0.1` instead to see if that helps

Comment: It's just going to remove URL

Comment: I'm so frustrated with the quality of firebase documentation right now. It's even worse if you're doing v2 and typescript. All sorts of assumptions they make in the docs don't hold and I have to scour SO for answers. Like why would they encourage people to use the v2 functions and then not bother to complete the documentation for it?